# How to write directly to database with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Basically i would like to bypass

```
def something=(string)
...
end
```

and do

```
create!(:something => "direct to database")
```

For some reason I'm having a hard time bypassing this function (i'm using this inside a migration).

Rails version is 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model.update_column(:col, 'value')
```

Comment: This is available since Rails 3.1, which [the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454375/montrealmike) needs. I wanted to add [this reference for further reading](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column), but somehow the edit got rejected.

Answer (score 3):

```
instance.update_attribute(:something,"direct to database") # bypass validation
```

Or

```
instance.something = "direct to database"
instance.save(validation = false)
```

Or

```
sql = "UPDATE models SET something = 'direct to database' WHERE id = #{object.id}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: the problem is not the validation (its the = overwritten), so your second option will definitely not work. The sql might just be the best option, will try it soon. Thanks